# Programmatically Open Word Document Located in the Computer in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file

I'm using WinForms. I have a form that has a button.

Goal: On button click: Open up a word document. Where the file path is hard coded into the program. I don't want the users to have to locate the word document.

Problem: I receive this error message. When I wrote my code, I get a red error line under 'Application'.

[image]

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        this.Application.Documents.Open(@"C:\Test\NewDocument.docx", ReadOnly:true)

    }
```

Comment: Just a wild guess, but are you are missing a field or property called `Application`?

Comment: @Roy what do you mean by field?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx

Comment: By the way, if you find that Word does not exit when your program shuts down, it may because of your codes use of _double dot_.  _[Never use 2 dots with com objects.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects)_.  It deals with Excel but the concept applies with Word.  e.g. `Application.Documents.Open()`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

first add the dll of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` to your references then add this:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

and use the following code:

```
Application ap = new Application(); 
Document document = ap.Documents.Open(@"C:\Test\NewDocument.docx");
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I had to do make word visible using `ap.Visible = true;`. Unless, it opened the document but with a invisible window.

Comment: @DanielBonetti Yes, that makes sense. Opening the application only starts the process, but not the interface. It's useful if you're processing Word documents in a way that does not require user interaction (switching format, encoding, etc). If you want to open the Word UI you need to specify it.

Comment: `The type or namespace name 'Application' does not exist in the namespace`

Answer (score 27):

Instead of adding interop in your reference, you may also consider to use this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Test\NewDocument.docx");
```

Comment: I prefer this method. That way, it will open up in any text editor; not necessarily MS Word.

Comment: I think this should be made as Answer.

Comment: Even better? `using var _ = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Test\NewDocument.docx");`.

Answer (score 6):

This `Application` is not `this.Application` it's `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application`.
So you can use this code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // Open a doc file.
    Application application = new Application();
    Document document = application.Documents.Open("C:\\word.doc");

    //Do whatever you want

    // Close word.
    application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: when i use "using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;" I get an error line under Office. Do i have to add something else? @aisa

Comment: It may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054184/cant-locate-microsoft-office-interop-word-in-reference-list

Comment: I was getting an error under (Application) application = new (Application()) and I was also getting an error under (Document)

Comment: Do you add Microsoft Office to your References?

Comment: I did. I was still getting an error on those 2 things. @aisa

Answer (score 6):

There is a good answer above which is:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Test\NewDocument.docx");
```

This should be modified for .Net Core 2 and above to be:

```
    var p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(filename)
    {
       UseShellExecute = true
    };
    p.Start();
```

Comment: only this work!!!! excelent solution!!!!