# How can I apply Word 2013 document made in VSTO in WPF form

Tags: c#, ms-word

Please bear with me, as I am a newbie c# coder, so this is probably a trivial question. I have successfully made a Word 2013 document template in it's own solution in VSTO.
In a seperate solution, I have a WPF project containing a form that has a button. What I fail to understand is how I call/open the Word document from this button? What should I put in the Button_Click event?

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you. 
Regards from the wannabe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically Open Word Document Located in the Computer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816364/programmatically-open-word-document-located-in-the-computer-in-c-sharp)

Comment: thanks garry, it gets me half way, but as I mention my Word document reside inside a solution - not in a local folder.

Comment: ok now I found a solution. I needed to publish the template project after designing. After that garry's link helped get me the rest of the way where I ended up using: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Test\NewDocument.docx");